# What will be the effect of putting a single phase load on an open delta transformer secondary?

Tags: transformer, three-phase, single-phase

Suppose I have an open delta transformer, 240 line to line secondary. I have a single phase constant power load I want to apply. I could apply it across either of the 'closed' phases and load that one phase. Presumably the two legs driving that phase on the primary will see all the load, completely ignoring the fact that the other transformer leg is present. But what happens if I load the 'open' phase? Will I see 240 volts still? Or something else? Will the load be distributed between all three legs on the primary side? Equally? What other effects can I expect?

Comment: If you have unbalanced loads you will detect uneven voltage drops/sag on the loaded phases.  The primary will see uneven current draw on the loaded legs of the transformer.  If you are approaching the full load values the results will be significant, if you are loading lightly you may not have much effects.